# Table with subheading and data

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, tablelayout

I have an activity calling xml layout. This xml layout file has Scrollview, LinearLayout, Radiogroup (with 2 buttons, btn1 & btn2), Textview (As heading of activity name), Tablelayout1 with tablerow1 and three textview as column headings. One more tablelayout2 with tablerow2 and three textview for data insertion (dynamically). I have three more activities and each activity has a set of 2D array and Hashmap. Since all three activities are providing different type of data, so before each activity insert its data to table, i want to add subheading for data and then respective activity data below it.

On app launching, tablelayout is invisible, now target is when btn1 is checked, tablelayout become visible with data and subheading of all three activities.

Comment: Got solution. This can be done by creating layout through Java instead of XML. Add all widgets through Java coding and get desired shapes and structure of layout. For adding data used intent get extras